# Wireless doesn't appear on my device

Tags: wifi

I have installed elementary os with a dual boot on my laptop. Nevertheless, I can't connect my computer to the wifi because the wireless icon doesn't appear in settings.
I've look in the web but I haven't find a working solution.
 Do you have any idea to help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
reinstall `libappindicator` and then logout and log back in.

Use the following command to reinstall `libappindicator`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libappindicator3-1 libappindicator1
```

If the above solutions doesn't work. Try reinstalling the network manager

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
```